# Reading multi-dimensional arrays from text file and storing the data in multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to read  multi-dimensional arrays from file HD.txt and store the data in arrays for computation. HD.txt looks like the following:

```
 [[[27],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
 [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
 [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]]

 [[102],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

I would like to read both of these arrays and store it in two separate arrays. For e.g. the first array in HD.txt is a 3 dimensional integer array (3X7X1 array) and the second array is a 2d integer array. I would like to read them as 3d and 2d arrays respectively.   I am not an expert in python and below is my attempt to read the first array. Needless to say it didnt work out as I wanted. Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
with open("HD.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f.readlines():
   S = line.split(' ')
```

Comment: Do you have any control on the data generation of the HD.txt file ?

Comment: the data is an output from a VC++ code. So, I can format it as I wanted. I tried to output it as a one dimensional array and read the data into a multi-dimensional array (after declaring it as I = np.empty((n,m,T),dtype=int) in python. Used for loop but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `line.split()` you need a character that is in between each of the values. Since `HD.txt` has commas in between each value you can simply remove each `[` and `]` character then call `split()`. Below is an example.

```
arrayOne = []
arrayTwo = []
next = False

with open("HD.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0] == '\n':
           next = True  
        else:          
            line = line.replace("[", "")
            line = line.replace("]", "")
            line = line.replace("\n", "")

            for i in line.split(','):
                if next:
                    arrayOne.append(i)
                else:
                    arrayTwo.append(i)
```

If the line is blank it means that the first character will be `\n` and you can start collecting the second array. Make sure to also remove the new line characters.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would like to read the content into a multi-dimensional array. I tried to convert it using for loops, but I got the following error: I[i][j][0] = arrayTwo[counter]
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

Comment: You mean instead of the way I have `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` you want a 2d array with `arrayOne` at `array[0]` and `arrayTwo` at `array[1]`?

Comment: Exactly a 2d array for arrayOne and 3d for arrayTwo

Comment: Can you put an edit on your post with the new code? I am unsure exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Just edited the original post

Comment: I get it now. That is definitely going to be a pain. Have you looked into `numpy`?

Comment: yes, i tried to convert the single dimensional arrayOne and arrayTwo with for loops. I declared one of the array as II = np.empty((n,m,T),dtype=int). First I got an error II[i][j][0] = arrayTwo[counter]
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '' Then I found an array element " " in arrayTwo. I guess its caused by "," at the end of each line. I manually removed the ","  and got it done.

Answer (score 0):

As you have control on the data generation, I advice you to remove the brackets and simply display data separated by spaces (for columns) and returns (for rows). It would lead you to this content for `HD.txt` :

```
27 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

102 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then to reconstruct your array, use the `split()` function from the `shlex` package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html). It separates stuff out of spaces. But, you have to convert each item to an `int` afterwards in your case. Which leads us to :

```
import shlex

array = []

with open("HD.txt", "r") as f:
 i = 0
 for line in f.readlines():
  array[i] = shlex.split(line)
  i += 1
```

Don't forget to cast the integer type for each value after that with `int()`